# telerik radgrid for showing image gallery

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to use telerik radgrid for showing an image gallery. The reason I will use the radgrid controller is for the ability to use the pager and to set sorting settings (so the images can sort in a way the user wants it to). 
The images will creates dynamically so the amount of images will be differ. For now the images will only be placed in one column, and I will ofcourse have it from left to right in different rows. I will do that without to have create specific columns, the reason to that is because the user shall have the ability to shrink and resize the content where the images are placed and then dynamically changes the amount of images in one row.
My question is if this can be possible with telerik RadGrid controls?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion for such functionality the RadListView control suits better then RadGrid. Check this demo of image gallery: [ListView / Image Gallery](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/listviewsliderwindowrotator/defaultcs.aspx?product=listview) Actually all these features may be implemented with ASP.NET ListView control.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a good solution for how you can use radGrid for ListView-or-DataList-like data presentation. 
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-listview-datalist-like-grid.html